# Link to image uploaded for a Post object in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, carrierwave

I can successfully create a Post in ActiveAdmin, and I can successfully upload an image to go with it. Now, my issue is that while the "Post#show" action will tell me the path to the image, I would like that to also be a link. I'm including a picture of what I'm talking about for clarity below.

[image]

In the very bottom field, it's clear that the image was successfully uploaded. ActiveAdmin even tells me where to find it, but the path it gives me is simple text. I would like it to be a link to that picture instead. Is there an easy `_path` function that I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve that is cutomizing your show page for Post model. It is also described in the official ActiveAdmin document of [Customizing the Show Screen](http://activeadmin.info/docs/6-show-screens.html)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  show do
    attributes_table_for resource do
      row :id
      row :title
      row :slug
      # ...
      row :image do
        span link_to(resource.image.path, resource.image)
        span img(src: resource.image.path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The other approach I think is possible is to extend ActiveAdmin's default [AttributesTable component](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/components/attributes_table.rb) to handle your image attribute.

Comment: Thats a huge help! Thank you! Now, do you know how I can add a path to the image directly under the image as it is shown? I know I can do it by adding another `row :image` underneath the block, but is there a way to do it within the `row :image do...end` block?

Comment: @elersong Updated my answer that adds a span to show the image. Please refer http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/12-arbre-components.html#text_node